# Immutable arraylists and manipulating objects

Tags: java, immutability

I'm making a game and one of the types of NPC's are artisans, who take items from your inventory and replace them with some other ones. 
The item class contains a type and a quantity, and the artisan has two arraylists: inside, with all of the items and their quantities, and outside with the same thing. 
Here is the trade method which performs the exchange.

```
public void trade(final ArrayList<thing> input)
{
    //commands=new ArrayList<Command>();
    boolean able=true;
    String s = "traded ";
    if(inside!=null)
    {
        for(thing w: inside)
        {
            able&=viable(input, w);
            s+=w+", ";
            if(able==false)
            {
                game.addmessage("you don't have enough "+w.text+"(s)");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else able=true;
    System.out.println(say);

    if(able==true)
    {
        System.out.println(say+" in:"+inside+" out: "+outside);
        s+=" for ";
        if(inside!=null)
        {
            for(thing q:inside)
            {
                remove(input, q);
            }
        }
        if(outside!=null)
        {
            for(thing r:outside)
            {
                game.additem(r);
                s+=r+", ";
            }
        }
        game.addmessage(s);

        //Interpret command, if any
        //interpret();

    }
    else 
    {
    }
}
public boolean viable(ArrayList<thing> input, thing t)
{
    for(int i=0; i< input.size(); i++)
    {
        if(input.get(i).type==t.type & input.get(i).quantity() >= t.quantity()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void remove(ArrayList<thing> input, thing t)
{
    int i=0;
    while(input.get(i).type!=t.type)i++;
    input.get(i).lower(t.quantity());
    if(input.get(i).quantity()<=0)input.remove(i);
}
```

A curious and extremely frustrating thing happens when I click to get the trade to go multiple times, all of which are valid trades and I do have enough of each item to make it go through. This is the output which should speak for itself:

free red gemn

free red gemn in:null out: [red gem (1)]

free red gemn

free red gemn in:null out: [red gem (1)]

free red gemn

free red gemn in:null out: [red gem (2)]

free red gemn

free red gemn in:null out: [red gem (4)]

free red gemn

free red gemn in:null out: [red gem (8)]

free red gemn

free red gemn in:null out: [red gem (16)]

free red gemn

free red gemn in:null out: [red gem (32)]

Why is this happening, even if the quantity field in the item class is made private? Why is the quantity changing?

Comment: Without reading through the whole programm in detail, the thing that immediately caught my eye is: You're talking about _immutable_ Arraylists. But Arraylists are not immutable. You've made them _final_ which means you can't exchange the list with another one but the content itself is still _mutable_ (changable)

Comment: btw.: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: I have no idea, but i do want the contents of items to remain immutable, thats why i made the fields private and only using getters and setters, but it still changes. how do I tell which java I am using?

Comment: I don't think you've yet understood what beeing immutable means. I've told you that `Arraylist`s are *not* immutable. You have to use Google Guava or something alike to have immutable datastructures. Java doesn't natively provide any...